# DNS timeouts between Hetzner Cloud VMs and Azure private DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, azure, udp, hetzner

> I have asked the same question already on [networkengineering.stackexchange.com](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84124/dns-timeouts-between-hetzner-cloud-vms-and-azure-private-dns), but it might be that it was not the right place to ask. so i was referred here.

We have the following setup

There are 12 Hetzner cloud (HC) server instances (all debian or ubuntu), most of them running jobs and services. Two acting as gateway server, sharing one HC Alias IP, and creating an IPSec tunnel (strongswan) to an Azure WAN. The HC servers share a private network, where the Alias IP of gateway servers is configured as gateway for the relevant routes.

In addition we have some important parts of our infrastructure at Azure, most importantly a private DNS zone, a virtual WAN, a virtual network, a MSSQL database, a private DNS resolver, and a couple of VMs for DNS forwarding via dnsmasq. (we introduced the DNS forwarders in addition to the private resolver after we had experienced our problem, but it hasn't changed anything). The virtual network has no special configuration, e.g. no firewall, no DDos protection and default DNS server. The private DNS is required to maintain private connection (with private IPs) to the database and the blob-storages from outside of Azure infrascructure.

And it works fine *most of the time*, **but** we have a serious <strike>problem</strike> challenge that sometimes some of our hosts experience DNS issues. In every case the duration of the timerange where the timeouts are happening is pretty much exactly one hour.  Until now the issue was never on more than one HC server at the same time, and it mostly affects server with high traffic, like one of our workers, and two monitoring servers running [Blackbox Exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter). On most HC servers we actually haven't observed this issue ever. Sometimes the issue doesn't happen for days anywhere. Then it happens one the same server two times with a few hours in between. We also observed a case, where only one connection times out.

One of our suspicions was that we might be affected of some rate limiting or quota exhaustion on one of the Azure products, e.g. the [DNS zone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#azure-dns-limits). The thing is that limits we have found cannot be the reason. On the one hand, e.g. worker-1 has a very high rate of DNS queries at times, and the issue doesn't occur. Than on the other hand we have the monitoring servers, where the DNS queries are really constant and rather low in count, but it does happen. [We have already asked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1375896/where-can-i-find-azure-(private)-dns-network-limit) for more infos on the usage limits, but of course the answer was not very satisfying.

Another thing we have observed in our [Node Exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) metrics that there is an increased UDP error rate (“NoPorts – UDP datagrams received on a port without a listener”.) on the inactive (!) Azure gateway during the exact period when the DNS timeouts happen on one of the servers. In addition, the same UDP error  (“port without listener”) does also happen on most other servers (not to all of them) with different patterns, even though they are configured identically as far as DNS is concerned.

We could reproduce the issue, or at least the symptoms, with [dnsblast](https://github.com/jedisct1/dnsblast). One time we did the test it happened after a few minutes, but another time only after more 30 minutes.

So it really looks like there is a bottleneck somewhere at certain times. But we do not know exactly where, and most importantly why.

- Other nameservers do work in this period, as does ping, etc
- The tunnel has a bandwidth of 500MB,we do not come even close to exceed that
- The issue happens less since we introduced the DNS forwarder azure VMs with some caching (dnsmasq), and local caching with systemd-resolved. But still around every other day
- resolv.conf options like `single-request` or `single-request-reopen` haven't helped
- The timeouts can be verified during the one hour timerange using `dig`
- The request is either timing out, or even no response comes back at all
- the DNS requests reach the forwarder (we turned on logging for dnsmasq), but apparently the response is not coming back
- it happens with both the [DNS private resolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-private-resolver-overview) and our own dnsmasq forwarder

Could the IPSec tunnel cause such a problem?
Do we have a routing problem?
But why only sometimes?
And how to analyze it?
If a firewall would cause this issue, it would be a permanent problem, right?
What could be the reason for so many UDP errors, where no port is listening? Especially on the inactive azure gateway-server?
Any ideas?

Thank you!